# How to use LIKE in tablix filtering with OR keyword in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a Table in my SSRS report and I want to filter the incoming data using a LIKE statement. The data looks like

```
CtrlNo  OtherColumns
J-123      ...
K-2340     ...
R-3352     ...
```

What I want to show in the table is the data where `CTRLNO` starts with `J-` or `R-`. So I am going to "tablix properties", then the section "filters" and add my filter as below.

[image]

It works when I do not use the "OR" statement, but with "OR' it gives an error, see below.

[image]

I could not find the correct syntax for my filter. I've tried those below but no luck:

="R-"+"*" OR "J-"+"*"

=(("R-"+"*") OR ("J-"+"*"))

How can I use LIKE filter for a tablix with OR keyword? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression:

```
="[R,J]-*"
```

It shows all rows where the first character is ***R***, or ***J*** and the second character is ***-***.